# Latex ACM template rowcolor in table

Tags: latex

I'm currently putting my master thesis into latex ACM template and I have a large table of which I would like different rows to have different colors. Now I know this normally is done using:

```
\rowcolor{Yellow}
```

Now I tried this using ACMYellow since that color seems to be defined in the acmart.cls file.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\textbf{Title}}                                                        \\ \hline
\textbf{\#} & \textbf{Header 1} & \textbf{Header 2} & \textbf{Header 3} & \textbf{Header 4} \\ \hline
1           & xx                & 1981562           & A                 & xx                \\ \hline
\rowcolor{ACMYellow}
2           & xx                & 782012            & A                 & xx                \\ \hline
3           & xx                & 130780            & B                 & xx                \\ \hline
4           & xx                & 123090            & A                 & xx                \\ \hline
5           & xx                & 82204             & A                 & xx                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \rowcolor 

l.556 \rowcolor
               {ACMYellow}
```

I am using the ACM template from Overleaf, which I think is a standard template for ACM style latex. Could someone tell me or point me in the right direction on how I can change the table row background color?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `colortbl` package and it should normally work with the `\rowcolor{Yellow}` command.

```
\usepackage{colortbl}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{5}{|l|}{\textbf{Title}}                                                        \\ \hline
\textbf{\#} & \textbf{Header 1} & \textbf{Header 2} & \textbf{Header 3} & \textbf{Header 4} \\ \hline
1           & xx                & 1981562           & A                 & xx                \\ \hline
\rowcolor{yellow}
2           & xx                & 782012            & A                 & xx                \\ \hline
3           & xx                & 130780            & B                 & xx                \\ \hline
4           & xx                & 123090            & A                 & xx                \\ \hline
5           & xx                & 82204             & A                 & xx                \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[Output using Overleaf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUv5x.png)